# Single CreateView in django for submitting multiple ModelForm data to multiple Model

Tags: python, django

I have a multiple modelforms form multiple model. I want one single CreateView for submitting all the values. I have three models(Employee, WorkExperience and Education). Models are connected using ForeignKey with each other.

forms.py:

```
class EmployeeAddModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Creates a form for employee invitations
    """
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = [
            'e_id',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'gender',
            'religion',
]
class WorkExperienceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Creates a form for saving employee work experiences
    """
    class Meta:
        model = WorkExperience
        fields = [
            'previous_company_name',
            'job_designation',
            'from_date',
            'to_date',
            'job_description',
        ]
class EducationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Creates a form for saving educational info of an employee
    """
    class Meta:
        model = Education
        fields = [
            'institution_name',
            'degree',
            'passing_year',
            'result',]
```

I have three model forms from three models in form.py. I want that my createview inherits all this modelforms and create a single form for posting data.

views.py:

```
class EmployeeAddView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    """
    Creates new employee
    """
    login_url = '/authentication/login/'
    template_name = 'employee/employee_add_form.html'
    form_class = EmployeeAddModelForm
    work_form_class = WorkExperienceForm
    queryset = Employee.objects.all()

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print(form.cleaned_data)
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)
    work_form = self.work_form_class(request.POST, prefix='work_form')
    education_form = self.education_form_class(request.POST, prefix='education_form')

    if form.is_valid() and work_form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save()
        work = work_form.save(commit=False)
        education = education_form.save(commit=False)
        work.employee = instance
        education.employee = instance
        work.save()
        education.save()

    if not education_form.is_valid():
        print("Education") 
        return redirect('employee:employee-list')

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('employee:employee-list')
```

I am rendering two forms from my view class. But when I use 'work_form' in my template.html, nothing appears.

How can I render all modelforms in my view?

Comment: add work_form to get(self, request, *args, **kwargs) function or get_context_data(self, **kwargs)

Comment: can you give me a detail code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### override get function, because get request can not get work_form in default

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = self.form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())
    work_form = self.work_form_class(prefix='work_form')
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form, 'work_form': work_form})
```

Comment: I have got another problem. Now it is not submitting data. @Blackdoor

Comment: plz ensure that the two forms should be in the same form tag block

Comment: Yes both are in same tag block. But I have to submit the form twice with same info.  At first it is creating emlpoyee then it is creating work experience. But this needs to done in one submission

Comment: does work experience model has a foreignkey to employee model?

Comment: if so, post method has a bug that the relationship was not been created.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217727/discussion-between-blackdoor-and-fahim-irfan).

Comment: should I pass related name(employee) of Employee model to Work model's foreign key field?

Comment: no need. related_name is for reversing relation from empoyee to work, this employee of work.employee just is a field name of foreignkey field in  work experience model.

Comment: Actually I have 3 model form. 3rd one is EducationForm(). After adding the 3rd form, no data has been saved if I hit submit button

Comment: maybe the 3rd form always be invalid, you can test it.

Comment: How can I test if it is valid or not??

Comment: oh, if not educationform.is_valid(): do_somthing

Comment: Can't I pass 3 modelforms??

Comment: i dont mean that. every form is independent. in some case, some fields is required but you dont include them in form fields, then form always is invalid. you can check the defination of fields in Education model.

Comment: I have edited my views.py. I tested that the form is invalid. But as you suggested, I checked the fields. It's okay

Comment: If i prints the error, it prints 'This field is required". But I am filling the form currectly